# how to display results(dataframe) from a python script in django

Tags: python, django, dataframe

```
class TweetAnalyzer():
    """"
    Class for tweet analysis
    """
    def tweet_to_data_frame(self, tweets):
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets ], columns=['tweets'])

        df['id']= np.array([tweet.id for tweet in tweets])
        df['len'] = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets])
        return df

#this is the python script class
```

views.py

```
from  Filmatory.tweetstream import TweetAnalyzer

def tweetsPageView(request):
    object = TweetAnalyzer()

    x = object.tweet_to_data_frame('pandas.txt')
    return render(request,'tweets.html',{'x':x.to_html})
```

Comment: Please try to explain what exactly is your problem in order to help other contributors to understand it and help you effectively. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article for more information

Answer (score 0):

In your template, you could use:

```
{{ x | safe }}
```

Or

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ x }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

To render your HTML in your template without Django sanitizing it.